# FpML 5.3 JAXB Bindings

Tags: jaxb, fpml

How do I use jaxb bindings to fix multiple group references in a schema?

Part of fpml 5.3 has the following in the schema

```
  <xsd:complexType name="Price">
<xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">A type describing the strike price.</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="commission" type="Commission" minOccurs="0">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">This optional component specifies the commission to be charged for executing the hedge transactions.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:choice minOccurs="0">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="determinationMethod" type="DeterminationMethod">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">Specifies the method according to which an amount or a date is determined.</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:group ref="EquityPrice.model" minOccurs="0"></xsd:group>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="amountRelativeTo" type="AmountReference">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">The href attribute value will be a pointer style reference to the element or component elsewhere in the document where the anchor amount is defined.</xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:group ref="EquityPrice.model"></xsd:group>
  </xsd:choice>
  <xsd:element name="cleanNetPrice" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">The net price excluding accrued interest. The "Dirty Price" for bonds is put in the "netPrice" element, which includes accrued interest. Thus netPrice - cleanNetPrice = accruedInterest. The currency and price expression for this field are the same as those for the (dirty) netPrice.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="quotationCharacteristics" type="QuotationCharacteristics" minOccurs="0">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Allows information about how the price was quoted to be provided.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

This results in

```
     * <p>
 * You are getting this "catch-all" property because of the following reason: 
 * The field name "GrossPrice" is used by two different parts of a schema. See: 
 * line 1361 of file:/C:/fpml-jaxb/src/main/xsd/fpml-asset-5-3.xsd
 * line 1361 of file:/C:/fpml-jaxb/src/main/xsd/fpml-asset-5-3.xsd
 * <p>
```

The error is misleading. EquityPrice.model starts with this and line 1361 is the grossPrice. The issue stems from above where there are 2 group references to EquityPrice.model in the Price complex type.

```
  <xsd:group name="EquityPrice.model">
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="grossPrice" type="ActualPrice" minOccurs="0">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">Specifies the price of the underlyer, before commissions.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
  </xsd:element>
```

The same thing applies for TradeNovationContent where it has multiple references to NewTrade.model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this same problem, the solution was to enable simple binding mode. 
Add the following into your external bindings file.

```
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
...
<jxb:globalBindings>
    <xjc:simple />
</jxb:globalBindings>
```

Error is caused by the way JAXB is handling groups, as you've seen yourself.